# Changing the database from unsigned zerofill to unsigned

Tags: mysql

I have a database in use for the public on a website and an app on google play; where the "id" column has the "unsigned zerofill" attribute.

I no longer want the leading zeros to be displayed. Example id = 00022504.

And would you like to know if modifying from unsigned zerofill to unsigned would affect website functionality or not?

I am grateful in advance for any input.

Comment: This sounds like something you should handle on the website if you don't want to modify the database structure

Comment: Understand. and in case I want to modify something in the database... would it affect the operation of my app or the website?

Comment: That depends on what your app or your website do with this data

Comment: I'm understanding you. Great contribution. I'm new to this.